# Run sh script after restart web server (puma)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, systemd, puma

How do you run sh script after starting(restarting) a Puma web server? (systemd systemctl)

Comment: check [`on_restart `](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/restart.md) ?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/puma.rb`

```
on_worker_boot do
  # Your shell script here executed with %x or system()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your systemd unit file, you can use the [ExecStartPost=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) directive to an additional command after startup.

Since `systemd` provides this feature, it's not necessary for every framework like Puma to duplicate it.